# How old is Ban?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Nanatsu no Taizai wikia says Ban is at least 1103 years chronologically.

[Ban - Nanatsu no Taizai wikia](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Ban)

But in season 2 of the anime, his adoptive father when they re-meet tells him he looks 20 for someone who should be 40. Also, in the wikia, his adoptive father age is 65, and his adoptive father knew him before he was inmortal and told him how to gain inmortality from a story he thought it was a fairy tail. So how old is Ban? Is he 40 or is he 1103 years old?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ban was around 23 years old when he drank from the fountain of youth...43 when the main evens of nanatsu no taizai take place.

After this, spoiler for future anime seasons*

> Ban entered purgatory where 1 minute is equal to 1 year in real life.
>  There he spent over 1060 years at least (in real time years)

Hope this helps you to understand!